# Vue3 Data Variables/Objects are undefined using Options API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I was using **Vue2** and refactored my project to use **Vue3**.

Did everything as it should be, but couldn't interact with `data() {..}`

Here's `data` setup :

```
data() {
    return {
        rules: {
            first: 1,
            second: 2,
            third: 3,
        },
        // ... and more variables & objects
    }
    
}
```

> I'm setting variables & objects in `data` some are constant and others are being changed in methods.

And using the `data`

`template` :

```
<input type="file"
    @change="changeEvent"
    :multiple="this.rules.first > 1"
/>
```

`methods` :

```
changeEvent() {
    if(this.rules.first == 1) { //.. do something }
}
```

Same as **Options API** as it was working with **Vue2**

But after upgrading to **Vue3** i get this `error` in the `console` :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'rules' of undefined
```

Also :

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush.
```

Also for all the `variables` and `objects` defined in the `data()`

I've read information about `Composition API` in `Vue3` and maybe i can use it, but for now i'm trying to save this project's life.

What i've read also that i can still use `Options API` along with `Vue3`.

So why the same `Options API` code isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this` inside template :

```
<input type="file"
    @change="changeEvent"
    :multiple="rules.first > 1"
/>
```